# Wordpress - Estilização da single

Tags: wordpress, post

Então, tenho um post type serviços e nele alguns posts, entre eles "noivas".

O que ocorre é o seguinte, a single single-qd-service.php foi estilizada, consequentemente todas as single das postagens do post type serviços, ficam estilizadas dessa forma, porém, uma das postagens não podem pegar essa estilização da single.

Como não saco tanto de php/wordpress, o que terei de fazer pra essa estilização não pegar na postagem que quero, já que a single é a mesma...

Comment: Essa postagem que não pode receber a estilização, possui alguma diferença das demais? Como uma tag, categoria, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito bem o seu caso mas no código dentro da página, o Loop que imprimi os posts, você terá que colocar condicionais(if) para saber distinguir seus posts e dai decidir se vai estilizá-los e como estilizá-los.

Comment: Consegui resolver, muito obrigado!